# type abstraction with comp data

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, type-level-computation

Only full applied types work in [`compdata`](https://github.com/pa-ba/compdata), if I am correct.

What is the fundamental limitation which makes it so ?

Are there ways to get around this ?

```
import           Data.Constraint 
import           Data.Comp.Ops
import           Data.Comp.Sum
import           Data.Comp.Term


data Val a = Val Int deriving Functor 
data Add a = Add a a deriving Functor 

-- Val is a subtype of Val :+: Add
works     = Dict :: Dict (Val :<: (Val :+: Add)) 

-- Does not work :<: requires fully applied types.... !!
notworks  = Dict  :: forall f . Functor f =>  Dict (f :<: (f :+: Add))
```

---

**Possible answer** : [p80](http://www.diku.dk/~paba/pubs/files/bahr14wgp-paper.pdf)

> The most important limitation is that `:≺:` only works for ground types,
>   i.e. neither side may contain variables. This is to be excepted since
>   we cannot rule out both ambiguity and duplication if the signatures on
>   either side of `:≺:` are not fully instantiated. For example, we may not
>   derive that `Val :≺: f :+: Val` , since if `f` were instantiated by `Val` ,
>   then the subsumption would be ambiguous.

So indeed, a general function like

```
notworks  = Dict  :: forall f . Functor f =>  Dict (f :<: (f :+: Add))
```

can not work.

---

**Possible answer ?**

However, it seems that given proofs `s :<: f` and `f :<: g`, I should be able to form the composite (as injectivity is preserved) `s :<: g`....

edit : something along the line of some 'completion'

```
data ReflI
data CompI

data InjectProof a io where
  ReflS :: Dict (f :<: g) -> InjectProof ReflI f g
  Comp :: InjectProof a f g -> InjectProof b g h  -> InjectProof CompI f h

class Injectable i f g where
   injectProof :: InjectProof i f g

instance (f :<: g) => Injectable ReflI f g where
    injectProof = ReflS Dict

instance (Injectable i f g, Injectable j g h) => Injectable CompI f h where
   injectProof = Comp (injectProof ::  InjectProof i f g)  (injectProof ::  InjectProof j g h)
```

---

**Possible answer #2 ?**

can't we say decorate the types with some levels

```
(Val,N) :≺: ((f, Suc N) :+: (Val, Suc N))
```

Then it is by construction injective, and we can defer giving the proof that each constructor in separate to when we apply it, allowing to strip of the index..

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept.